# how can i put this configuration on my huawei cellphone?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My problem is that on my cellphone huawei my services are killed so I need to change the settings on my cellphone.

My problem is the same than [this](https://telegram.org/faq#notification-problems)

> NOTE: Huawei and Xiaomi devices have evil task killer services that interfere with the Telegram notification service. For our notifications to work, you need to add Telegram to allowed apps in those devices' security settings. Huawei: Phone Manager App > Protected Apps > Add Telegram to the list. Xiaomi: Services > Security > Permissions > Autostart, find Telegram and enable autostart.

So I need to change the configuration programmatically for my huawei cellphone I need to do this:

Phone Manager App > Protected Apps > Add myApp

Would appreciate some help! :-)

**Edit**

Why the negative votes, a lot of people have the same problem? My question is how can I change programmatically the settings of my cellphone?

Comment: I got the same problem. Don´t care about negatigve votes, sometimes I feel like some poeple doesn´t read the questions, but voting down....

Comment: @hvar90 **Did you found any solution?**

Comment: @bdevloper no, i did not

Answer (score 0):

No,you can not do that. Unless you get root.

Comment: i mean how did be able whatsapp to put this configuration programmatically?  sorry for my english

Comment: Huawei and Xioami companies whitelist the popular apps like Facebook, Whatsapp and Messenger in AutoStart. Other apps need to inform the user to enable their app in AutoStart manually.